# JavaScript audio playing multiple times whilst using same audio object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, html5-audio

I've got a function to play JavaScript audio like the following:

```
  playSound(sub) {
    console.log(sub);
    if (sub.audio.paused) {
      sub.audio.ontimeupdate = function (i) {
        if ((this.currentTime / this.duration) > 0.9) {
          this.currentTime = 0;
          this.play();
        }
      };
      sub.audio.play();
    } else {
      sub.audio.pause();
      sub.audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
  }
```

I call this function in my HTML like so:

```
(click)="playSound(sub)"
```

All is well and working perfectly fine until i programatically try to play the audio, i call the playSound() function in another function in an if-statement. The audio plays succesfully but whenever i try to call the exact same function in the HTML with the above (click) function with (as far as i know) the exact same Audio object given in the parameter, the sound plays double?

Is it a caching issue? or an Angular issue which makes a copy of the original so the audio instance plays multiple times?

I've tried HowlerJS also which gave me the exact same problem, Howler seemed to make different ID's upon playing.

This is where the playSound function gets called

```
  setSleepyset() {
    this.muteAll();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.items[i].subitems.length; x++) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.items[i].subitems[x].audio.src) !== null) {
          this.playSound(this.items[i].subitems[x]);
        } else {
          this.items[i].subitems[x].audio.pause();
          this.items[i].subitems[x].audio.currentTime = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is where the HTML audio objects are made:

```
items = [
    {
      category: "Weather",
      expanded: true,
      subitems: [
        {
          name: "Rain",
          background: "../assets/backgrounds/rain.jpg",
          sound: "../assets/sounds/rain.ogg",
          audio: new Audio('../assets/sounds/rain.ogg'),
          icon: "../assets/icons/rain.png",
          playing: false
        },
        {
          name: "Thunder",
          background: "../assets/backgrounds/thunder.jpg",
          sound: "../assets/sounds/thunder.ogg",
          audio: new Audio('../assets/sounds/thunder.ogg'),
          icon: "../assets/icons/thunder.png",
          playing: false
        },
        {
          name: "Wind",
          background: "../assets/backgrounds/wind.jpg",
          sound: "../assets/sounds/wind.ogg",
          audio: new Audio('../assets/sounds/wind.ogg'),
          icon: "../assets/icons/wind.png",
          playing: false
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

The goal is to play multiple sounds at the same time and load them at the same time, a global Audio variable is not a solution unless i can play / pause multiple audio sources within the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Turns out i called the function from another instance, i used a provider which created a new instance of the Home Class, creating a new Audio object every time playSound was called from the sidemenu.